# How to automate a subfolder creation for existing folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, workflow

I was asked to create 2022 folders in each property folder that we have on our SharePoint site. We have the folders setup: Location > Properties > 2021.

I am trying to figure out a way to automate the creation of the 2022 folders. I am hoping for a solution that would allow me to provide the location folder path and then have it create a 2022 folder within each property folder that exists in that location folder.